# Where are Properties.Settings.Default outputted for a .Net Core WinForms application?

Tags: .net-core, settings

I am new to .Net Core 3.1 and was looking at creating my first WinForms app using it.  All seemed fairly straight forward but when I looked at the published output, I couldn't find any of the app settings from my Settings.settings file.  Using the Framework, these would be found in the app config file so I thought they'd show up in one of the JSON files published with my .Net Core app but as mentioned, I don't see them anywhere.  For my existing Framework based WinForms, I edit the settings in their app config files quite a bit to control functionality between instances without having to update the application.  Thus, having those settings accessible to modify in a .Net Core WinForms app without having to recompile is a must.  I've seen postings where others add a config file and use that. So, perhaps Settings should no longer be used?

Answer (score 0):

It is not stored in the project folder
but rather it is saved in its temporary files.
It is stored in the user account on the device.

```
c: / User / {name user} / AppData /local /{folder name project}
```

You can found folder with the name of your project in this path. 
If you delete it, all the temporary data that are saved will be deleted by

```
Properties.Settings.Default
```